# What is quantum states of a gas? Is it the principle quantum no.?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

When we write that the possible quantum states of a system are $S=1,2,3.\dots$, how is that related with the four quantum numbers, especially with the spin of a particle? Also according to BE statistics,there is no limit on the number of particles that can occupy the same quantum state, so if we consider a beam of photons(bosons), then, will all the individual photons have the same values for all quantum numbers or any other quantum parameters?

Comment: What are "the four quantum numbers"? If you're talking about $n,l,m,s$ for atom orbitals, they have nothing to do with states that are not orbitals.

Comment: In simple words,what does it mean when it says that a gas has certain values of quantum states,say s=1,2,3... ?

Answer (score 1):

You say "the four quantum numbers", by which I assume you mean $n, l, m, s$ of atomic spectroscopy. It's important to realize that this set of quantum numbers only applies in (simple) spectroscopy. It is not the case that any random quantum system is characterized by these four numbers. When a statistical mechanics book says to sum over states $s_1, s_2, \dots$, it usually means all possible states of the system. Some of these will be eigenstates of the confining potential (it's popular to use particles-in-a-box wave functions). Some of these may be internal states. For instance, if your gas is VERY hot, you may indeed need to sum over different $n, l, m, s$ states because the thermal energy may be large enough to excite electronic states.

> so if we consider a beam of photons(bosons), then, will all the individual photons have the same values for all quantum numbers or any other quantum parameters?

I'm not particular sure about the beam aspect, since usually people talk about a gas confined to a volume of some kind. It is the case that a box of bosons *at zero temperature* are all in the ground state, but not for finite/real temperatures.

Comment: Does that imply that each boson gas molecule is exactly identical to all the other molecules,in every aspect of quantum parameters?

Comment: Yes. The key thing that makes bosons/fermions behave the way they do is that they are entirely interchangeable. I think Griffiths gets poetic about it and says "not even God can tell them apart"